# Maths probability Logic that doesn't make sense to me

Tags: probability

Here's a probability question I came across:

> The attendance at a GAA match depends on the weather. The probability of a large crowd attending is $0.9$. The probability of large crowd attending if it is raining is $0.3$. The probability of it raining on match day is $0.2$. Calculate the probability of a large crowd attending the match given it is raining.

The answer is supposed to be $0.06$, but logically it doesn't make sense to me. It already tells you that the probability of a large crowd attending if it is raining is $0.3$ but then in the solutions it does $(0.2)(0.3)$. The only way there would be $0.3$ to begin with was if it was raining, why do I need to factor in if it is raining when it is already raining.

Comment: Are you sure it was 0.6? or was it 0.06?

Comment: @EmilioMartinez 0.06 sorry * but I still dont get it :/

Comment: I agree with you (are you sure you read the question correctly?). $0.06$ is the probability of a large crowd attending **and** it is raining.

Comment: I figured.
The way you tell it, they asked you to calculate "large crowd attending the match **given** it is raining" and the answer 0.06 is for "large crowd attending the match **and** it is raining". Either you misunderstood something, or whoever wrote it was a bit careless, but if they answered 0.06 is the only thing that makes sense to me. Why add the 0.9 thing, i don't know. Was this the only question or were there more in the excercise?

Comment: These numbers don't seem to add up.  We have $0.9$ chance of a large crowd rain or shine, but $(1-0.3)*0.2 = 0.14$ chance of a small crowd in the rain.  These add up to $1.04 > 1$, but they're mutually exclusive, so should add up to $1$ or less.

Comment: @EmilioMartinez that was a literal copy and paste of the question, and that is the whole question. So am I right on the grounds of the question wasn't written correctly or I just really dont understand what is going on :/

Comment: given what @DanUznanski pointed out, the problem is wrong all around. If it's from some elementary book, I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: @EmilioMartinez lmao it is from a leaving cert mock paper (Like the final exam before college). I don't know what other countries are like but I feel like our Maths exams are more like English exams sometimes, trying to figure out what the questions mean.

Comment: @DanUznanski welp I think the Irish Exam Paper makers need new staff then haha

Comment: @AlexCollins mind you, in college you will still come across seldom errors, increasingly difficult to figure out, but nowhere this embarrassing for the makers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something has definitely gone wrong here.

"The probability of A if B" is typically read the same as "The probability of A given B": we divide $P(AB)/P(B)$.  We already have that, so the answer should be just $0.3$.

The answer given is "the probabilty of A and B" $P(AB)$, that is, the probability of a large crowd in the rain, and uses this calculation: $P(AB) = \frac{P(AB)}{P(B)} \times P(B)$.

But something worse is happening too: the numbers don't make sense!  With the information we have, we can determine the probability of all four scenarios, and this is where something goes wrong.  We have $P(AB) = (0.3)(0.2) = 0.06$, $P(AB')=P(A)-P(AB)=0.9-0.06=0.84$, and ... $P(B')=1-0.2=0.8$, and that's smaller than one of its two components!  In a hundred match season we'll have $84$ large crowds on sunny days but only $80$ sunny days.